# Encapsulating iOS logic

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, uitextfield

I am creating a `UITextField` that will format numbers.  My initial thought was that I would subclass `UITextField` and the logic to format the numbers would be added to this subclass.  My thinking is that this logic has nothing to do with my main ViewController and it should be encapsulated into the control itself.

So now I have a subclass. All I need to do now is listen for an event such as `- (BOOL)textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange: replacementString:`.

However it seems that setting the delegate to self is not good design practice, which I have to say I was a little surprised. It makes complete sense to me to encapsulate the control logic in the subclass rather than a view controller or a completely separate class.

My current approach is to add a target action to the `UITextField` which listens for any changes - but this doesn't feel right.  I want to use the delegate but it seems that's frowned upon.

So if delegate methods are only meant to be handed off to other objects, how are objects supposed to encapsulate logic related to those events, without using notifications or KVO or similar?

Why should the handling of events be handed off to say a ViewController when really it's the control that should handle that logic?

Comment: In my opinion, it's not a bad practice to use delegate methods like `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` inside the View controller class. In fact, it is a very common practice and usually, to avoid breaking the MVC, it is the right place to put that methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS/OS X, it is uncommon to give UI elements a lot of own logic as this violates the Model-View-Presenter design of Cocoa (Apple calls it Model-View-Controller, but the Cocoa MVC is not like the classic MVC but rather like MVP). In MVP, views are as dump as possible. Their only task is to display what they've been told to display. That's why they are called "Presenters", they shall only present something.

And in Cocoa it is uncommon to extend functionality by subclassing. Cocoa is designed around composition and delegation. So you you build complex components out of simple components (this is called composition) and have a delegate to customize functionality, so it's usually not required to subclass your class for that.

The logic of a UI element is usually within a controller object. Model is the data, controller is the logic, presenter/view is just the UI.

[image]

If you want to encapsulate all this within a single class, don't use subclassing, use composition. Subclass `UIView` to create a custom view and use a normal `UITextField` within that view: created it programmatically, keep it in an instance variable (or a private property), add it to yourself as a subview (`[self addSubview:...]`) and then set yourself as its delegate to handle events.

Of course subclassing `UIView` is also subclassing, but subclassing `UIView` is the only way to create a custom view (otherwise `UIView` would have to be a protocol) and it's very easy, as you hardly need to override anything and what you need (or maybe want) to override is pretty well documented.

Consider `UIView` to be actually designed for subclassing (the documentation has plenty of notes regarding subclassing), `UITextField` is not (the word subclassing is not even present in its documenation). Objective-C has no `final` keyword to prevent subclassing, so by convention, consider all classes final unless there are subclassing notes (if there was such a keyword, `UITextField` would most like be `final`).

Comment: There is basically no practical difference to subclassing UIView and embedding a UITextField and subclassing UITextField directly.

There is a downside with your approach, in that extra resources are required to do exactly the same task.

Comment: @Avi There is a difference: UIView is designed for subclassing (the documentation has plenty of notes regarding subclassing), UITextfField is not (the word subclassing is not even present in its docs). Objective-C has no final keyword to prevent subclassing, so by convention, consider all classes final unless there are subclassing notes (if there was such a keyword, UITextField would certainly be final).

Comment: @Avi And it makes a difference in terms of delegate: You shall never be your own delegate. Even if you subclass, it must still be possible to set an external delegate. If Apple wanted you to subclass UITextField, they would explain what methods to override to get all the infos/events the delegate gets without being the delegate, so that even your subclass can still have an external delegate (that's how they do it for all classes intended for subclassing).

Comment: Good points.  You can work around the delegate issue, but it's definitely not the best approach.

Comment: Thank you both - so it seems the preferred approach would be to subclass a UIView and encapsulate the logic there.